# Generalization of $\int_0^\alpha \sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta>\sqrt{\alpha^2+\sin^2\alpha}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

I came across a problem that required proving a specific case and then going on to generalize it. While I have no problem with the first part, I need some confidence from someone about the second part. Here we go.

**The problem statement**:

1. Show that for $\displaystyle 0<\alpha\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$
   $$
   \int_0^\alpha \sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta>\sqrt{\alpha^2+\sin^2\alpha}\tag{1}
   $$
2. Generalize the result in part (1).

**My Answer Attempt**:
Clearly, LHS of $(1)$ represents the length of the curve $f(\theta)=\sin\theta$ from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\alpha$ and the RHS represents the distance from the origin to the point $(\alpha,\sin\alpha)$, that is the length of the line from origin to the said point.

[image]
*Curve in red and Line in blue.*

Since both the curve and the line pass through the origin, and the shortest distance between two points is a straight line, we have $(1)$ proven.

**The generalization that I've come up with:**

> For any continuous (not necessarily smooth) curve $f(x)$ in $[0,a]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
> $$\left |\int_0^a \sqrt{1+\big[f'(x)\big]^2}dx\right|\geq \sqrt{a^2+\big[f(a)\big]^2} $$ Equality holding if the curve is a
> straight line or $a=0$.

This is basically saying that the shortest distance between two points is a straight line. The points in our case being the origin and a point on the curve $f(x)$.

The curve has to pass through the origin because otherwise the relation may not hold true. Example: The curve $f(x)=3$ in $[0,\infty)$.

Is this good?

Comment: Interesting problem. It works perfect for $f(x)=\tan(x)$ and, for this case, $$\text{lhs - rhs}=\frac{a^5 \left(23 a^2+42\right)}{1890 \sqrt{2}}+\cdots$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I didn't get you...

Comment: I took this case to give an example. Unfortunately, I cannot make a proof for the general case but I have the feeling that your conjecture is correct. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Gotcha

Comment: For $f(x)=x^n$, it works.

Comment: Does the generalization necessarily require taking $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ as $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$?  Could you recognize $sin^2(x) + cox^2(x) = 1$ so that $\sqrt({sin^2(x)}) = sin(x)$  is the left hand integral?  Is that too specific?  That is how I see the problem, recognizing sin(x) is a bounded curve.

Comment: Of course I meant  $\sqrt({2 + sin^2(x)})$.  You would then make a generalization for alpha.

Comment: I am a bit confused why the reasoning you proposed (shortest path is the linear line) should not apply to the general case directly. Could you clarify that for me?

Comment: @Thomas The reasoning does apply to the general case.

Comment: So you just wanted a confirmation of the fact that the reasoning apply to the general case? By the way nice trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality naturally only makes sense for continuously differentiable $f$. We will use that if $F$ and $G$ are continuously differentiable, and $F(0)=G(0)$ and $F'(y) \geq G'(y)$ for all $y \in [0,z]$ then $F(y) \geq G(y)$ on that interval.

Equality holds for $a=0$. Differentiating both sides w.r.t $a$ gives
$$\sqrt{1+(f'(a))^2} \geq \frac{a+f(a)f'(a)}{\sqrt{a^2+f(a)^2}}$$
Which after squaring both sides and rearranging amounts to
$$a^2f'(a)^2 + f(a)^2 \geq 2a f(a) f'(a)$$
or
$$ (f(a)-a f'(a))^2=0.$$
Insisting that this holds for all $a$ is easily seen to imply linearity of $f$.

Comment: I think you should mention that $F'(x)\geq G'(x)$ for all $x\in[0,a]$ implies $F(x)\geq G(x)$

Comment: @ThomasBakx I've made some edits to the question.

Comment: What edits exactly?

Comment: The absolute value signs are not necessary.

Comment: @ThomasBakx I don't think the function should be continuously differentiable. It can have a finite number of non-differentiable points like cusps or sharp corners etc...

Comment: If $f$ is piecewise $C^1$ and continuous, just apply the proof to each interval on which $f$ is $C^1$ and conclude by using the triangle inequality.  I'm just saying that if $f$ is merely continuous, you'll need to think about your definition of 'arc length'. The formula involving $f'$ makes no sense in that case. Moreover, I'm pretty sure you can construct continuous functions for which 'arc length' is very hard to make sense of.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562210/arc-length-of-non-differentiable-functions.

Comment: @ThomasBakx I see. I'm yet to learn math to that level.

Comment: No problem! Please don't forget to accept my answer, if you're happy with it :)

Answer (score 1):

My "geometrically" solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYgjx.png

Comment: Please typeset your answer using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but some ideas: The integral involved in the problem is an *Elliptic integral* and maybe can be analyzed with the theory of this functions

Recall the incomplete [elliptic integral of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html):

$$E(\varphi,k) = \int_{0}^{\varphi} \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \theta}d\theta$$

where $k^2<1$

Then the left hand side of the inequality is

$$
\int_0^\alpha \sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta = \int_0^\alpha \sqrt{2-\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta = \sqrt{2} \int_0^\alpha \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta = \sqrt{2} E\left(\alpha, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$

[Here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.9.E12) is a formula which states that

$$\max \left(\sin \phi, \phi\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \phi} \right)\leq E(\phi,k)\leq \phi$$

Therefore

$$\max \left(\sin \alpha, \alpha\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 \alpha} \right)\leq E(\alpha,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$

Hence

$$\boxed{\int_0^\alpha \sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta\geq \sqrt{2} \max \left(\sin \alpha, \alpha\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 \alpha} \right)}$$
This inequality is far from being the one we look for but I hope it works as food for thought